# 2012 Sonata doesn't turn on but make hosh sound

Tags: battery, ignition, starter

I have 2012 Hyundai Sonata which does not turn on,(Sometime you get lucky and turns on.)
The car makes hush sound as below link but doesn't turn on.

[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jn4HwrI8ba2I3pboVFNjrVo85AS6v58v/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see in video i tried couple time but this time I got lucky.

I have tired jumped the car, no lock
All light turns on

What this could be.

Answer (score 1):

The sound you are hearing is the starter gear spinning and not engaging the flexplate and therefore the engine will not turn over and start the car. This could be caused by a couple of things.

Most likely a weak starter. Because it is weak and slowly failing every so often it does engage the flexplate and starts the car. The solution is to replace the starter.

Another possibility, but less likely, is a weak battery not providing enough voltage to the starter so it cannot engage the flexplate and start the car. If you have a multimeter you can check the battery voltage. It should be 12.4-12.7 volts with engine off. If you don't have a multimeter you can take your car to an auto retail chain (e.g. Napa, AutoZone, Pep Boys) and they will check your battery voltage for free.

Comment: The battery voltage is 12.51V and when you turn on the ignition it goes down to 11.47V
So base on these the starter is bad.

Comment: Based on the voltage information you shared it looks to be a bad starter.